# Pickle Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pickle, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'd like to "pickle" a Spark DataFrame object and have tried the following:

```
import pickle
data = sparkContext.jsonFile(data_file) #load file
with open('out.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(data, handle)
```

If I convert "data" to a Pandas DataFrame (e.g., using data.toPandas()), the above code works.  Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Even if it was possible, it wouldn't work as expected.  Why it is not possible? Because DataFrame is just a wrapper around JVM object. Why it wouldn't work as expected? Because DataFrame, same as RDD is just a recipe. It doesn't contain data.

Comment: you could save it as a parquet file using '<yourdf>.write.parquet(<filename>.parquet)': http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions

Comment: I would like to save just the pointer to the DataFrame, so that I can pass it between threads.  Ideally, I don't want to write/read a file to pass the reference to the DataFrame to another thread.